# SQL swap field values where another field is not the same

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have the following table:-

```
Table Idsets

Id  UserGroup

1    A
1    B
1    C
2    A
2    D
```

I want to be able to swap the Id values

I have tried :-

```
UPDATE Idsets
SET Id = CASE Id WHEN '1' THEN '2' ELSE '1'END;
```

This fails with the error message  "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object" ..etc.

What I think I need to do is prevent the Id field value being swapped if the UserGroup field value is the same.

Could anyone help me construct a WHERE clause to be added to the case statement that would only swap the Id field values if the UserGroup field is different?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this in two steps:

```
UPDATE Idsets
    SET Id = CASE Id WHEN '1' THEN '-1' ELSE '-2'END;

update idsets
    set id = (case id when '-1' then '2' else '1' end);
```

It seems that you have a unique index or composite primary key on `id, UserGroup`.  So, when you change the row `(1, 'A')` to `(2, 'A')` (or vice versa) you are getting a duplicate error.

EDIT:

Based on your comment about excluding certain updates:

```
upate idsets
     SET Id = CASE Id WHEN '1' THEN '2' ELSE '1'END
    where not exists (select 1
                      from idsets i2
                      where ((i2.id = '1' and idsets.id = '2') and (i2.UserGroup = idsets.UserGroup)) or
                            ((i2.id = '2' and idsets.id = '1') and (i2.UserGroup = idsets.UserGroup))
                     )
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, unfortunately Id is a foreign key and cannot be temporarily set to a value that does not exist in the other table.

Comment: I've tried to get this amendment to work - unfortunately still getting the duplicate key problem - it appears to process the swap before the where clause.